# Finding the form Id in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a main page (Home.aspx) and on selecting a link from the menu i send an asynchronous request to the server and load the response (another aspx page) inside jquery tabs.

Now i have different hyperlinks inside the pages and on click i call a method in an external js file. How do i get the form id of the clicked hyperlink.

To be simple on click of a hyperlink calls a method, will i get the id of the form  to which the hyperlink belongs.

Comment: Please post your code. Or at least _some_ code...

Comment: Showing us the code would really help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't use a javascript toolkit/framework and don't care to learn good practises and simply want to get the job done.

```
<!-- inside a form somewhere -->
<a href="url" onclick="javascript:doStuff(this);">link text</a>

<!-- somewhere else in your page, where you put javascript -->
<script>
    function doStuff(node) {
        var ancestor = node.parentNode;
        var formID;
        while( ancestor && ancestor !== document ) {
            if ( /^form$/i.test( ancestor.nodeName ) ) {
                formID = ancestor.id;
                break;
            }
            ancestor = node.parentNode;
        }
        if ( formID ) {
            // do stuff with formID
        }
    }
</script>
```

If you use jQuery:

```
$("form a").click(function(e){
    var formID = $(this).closest("form").attr("id");
    if( formID ) {
        // do stuff with formID
    }
});
```

Comment: i am using asp.net mvc, the above code gives me the form object of the Main Form not the Form which is inside the jquerytab..

Comment: Ah so your link isn't even inside the form? Or are you nesting forms? From you question it kinda seemed the link was inside the form.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how your code looks like, but what you are asking would be something like

```
$("#container a").click(function () {
    if($(this).parent().attr('id') == "the_form_you_need") {
        do_stuff_with_it();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to walk the DOM tree starting at the link node and going up by parent until you find a form node. Conceptually the code would look something like this:

```
node = link;
while (node.type != form) {
    node = node.parent;
}
form.id = node.id;
```