# How to manage different form contexts of same form element in single DOM tree

Tags: javascript, html, dom

As my question title could be bit unclear to you (I tried best), following is what I'm exactly trying to do.

I'm having a form element (say a user_info form), where such form elements will be generated for different users by java script and displayed in different js tabs (example: dojo tabs).

once form elements are generated, later I need to react on user actions performed on different html elements defined *inside* user_info form. In this case I need to identify what is the context (in which user_info form element) in which user is working on. The simplest example would be how to retrieve form id of the form in which user actions are being performed.

According to my understanding, I can not simply retrieve from by form id, because now DOM tree contains duplicate form instances of the same from element. So, IS there anyway, I could identify form context based on the user actions on its input elements.

Thank You.

Comment: Duplicated elements (e.g. with the same name / id) isn't the best approach.

Comment: First, you absolutely should **not** put multiple elements with the same "id" value onto your page.  The "id" value of every element on the page must be either empty (that is, no value) or a **unique** value.

Comment: No, I need to identify different form ids uniquely to perform operations, simply if user click edit button, only need to save relevant form.

Comment: @pointy, I agree, it must be unique, thus I can generate it dynamically, the real problem is how to retrieve relevant form Id.

Comment: So you are having multiple instances of a form structure (same structure) one for every user and you want to save *only* the corresponding user's info when that form's save button is clicked. Is that the correct requirement?

Comment: You don't really have the exact same form element in multiple forms. You have *copies* of form elements, but each one really is a separate node in the DOM.  Thus, from each form element you can find its containing `<form>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From any form element, you can locate the form that contains an element simply by checking the element's "form" property. If you're handling events, then the event object will give you the target. If your forms have "submit" elements in them, then native browser behavior will be to only submit that one affected form anyway.

*edit* So for example if you have a handler for "click" events bound somehow:

```
function clickHandler(ev) {
  ev = ev || window.event;
  var theForm = ev.target.form; // find the form from the target element
  if (form) {
    // do whatever you need to do to here
  }
}
```

Comment: basically I'm not expecting to handle onSubmit event, but to handle onClick event of custom button. In this case, could you please provide me a vary simple example on how to retrieve values of element values of relevant user form?

Comment: +1 for the concise solution. here is a working fiddle applying the idea - http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepan_nits/pzuAD/10/

Answer (score 0):

If you are having multiple form structures with as many `<form></form>` tags as there are users, and you have the action buttons inside every form instance

**Method 1**
- you can get the parent form element of the action button which you clicked using the code given in this answer [Finding the form Id in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274704/finding-the-form-id-in-javascript/4274896#4274896) It contains javascript as well as jquery code. When you have the corresponding form ID, you can manipulate its data.

**Method 2**
- assuming that you are generating the forms elements using javascript, you are probably assigning some numbers as part of the form names. say `form_22` (for user with ID 22), `form_24` etc., you can assign the same numbers as part of IDs to the action buttons inside those forms, so after generation and assignments, your forms look like this:-

```
<form name="user_22">

following are input fields
<input "data1_22">
<input "data2_22">

following are action inputs
<input name="edit_22" id="edit_22" onclick="editForm();" />
<input name="some_other_action_24" id="some_other_action_24" onclick="otherActionForm();" />

</form>

<form name="user_24">

following are input fields
<input "data1_24">
<input "data2_24">


following are action inputs
<input name="edit_24" id="edit_24" onclick="editForm(this);" />
<input name="some_other_action_24" id="some_other_action_24" onclick="otherActionForm();" />

</form>
```

So, that you can prepare the form ID inside the js functions and operate on the form data

```
function editForm(object)
{
   var formNumber = str_replace("edit_","",object.name);
   //Get javascript str_replace from https://github.com/kvz/phpjs/raw/master/functions/strings/str_replace.js
   var formName = "user_"+formNumber;

   //Get form params and do what you want
   document.formName.data1_+formNumber;
   document.formName.data2_+formNumber;
}
```

Comment: you are welcome. nice if it helped even a little bit. I guess you are using the solution given be @Pointy, however. So, did my solution help you in visualizing the situation or something else? I wish to improve rapidly the quality of my solutions. Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Much appreciate the way you organize your solution. Thus, as you may agree, @Pointy's answer is much concise & manageable. With Your answer, certainly it achieve same expected functionality, but manageability of such solution could be tedious. I had a similar thought like your solution before I put Q? here, but I believe, our html gurus are not mad as us to write whole lot of code to achieve this simple functionality. I hope I help, where you need to now focus :)

Comment: Thanks @nimp. Actually I didn't know that form object could be retrieved like that. I agree @Pointy's solution is a very nice one. I have added a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepan_nits/pzuAD/10/ . It may help others.